# NSNotificationCenter in Swift Not Behaving Correctly (only calls certain things in the function)

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, nsnotificationcenter

I'm using `NSNotificationCenter` to trigger `tableView.reloadData()` upon receiving data via an http request. 99% of the time, the `tableView` does not reload. Only after terminating the app, deleting, cleaning, and again running does it operator...but only the first time.

**MainVC.swift**

```
import UIKit
class MainVC: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

let needMetNotificationKey = "kNeedMetKey"
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: "needMet", name: needMetNotificationKey, object: nil)
}

func needMet() {
    startConnectionAt(url)
    tableView.reloadData()
    println("executed")
}
func startConnectionAt(urlPath: String){
    var url: NSURL = NSURL(string: urlPath)
    var request: NSURLRequest = NSURLRequest(URL: url)
    var connection: NSURLConnection = NSURLConnection(request: request, delegate: self, startImmediately: false)
    connection.start()
}
```

**AcceptVC.swift**

This is the VC that presents my form and makes the http request, whereafter returning to the MainVC.

```
import UIKit
class AcceptVC: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet var receiveName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var receiveEmail: UITextField!
@IBOutlet var receivePhone: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
@IBAction func signupForNeed() {

    var URL: NSURL = NSURL(string: "http://www.domain.com/json.php")
    var request: NSMutableURLRequest = NSMutableURLRequest(URL:URL)
    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    var needName = receiveName
    var needEmail = receiveEmail
    var needPhone = receivePhone

    var signup: String = "id=\(passedID)&name=\(needName.text)&email=\(needEmail.text)&phone=\(needPhone.text)"
    request.HTTPBody = signup.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response, data, error) in println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    }

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(needMetNotificationKey, object: nil, userInfo: nil)

    navigationController?.presentingViewController?.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: {})
    }
```

I've added the `println("executed")` to the end of the `needMet()` function to verify that it does make it to the end of function. Reliably, "executed" is always printed.

When I utilize startConnectionAt(url) and tableView.reloadData() anywhere else it behaves as it should. Why does it not operate as it should here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're posting your notification immediately after your request is sent, not once it's finished. You need to move the `postNotificationName` call inside your completion closure on `sendAsynchronousRequest`:

```
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
    (response, data, error) in 

    println(NSString(data: data, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding))
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(needMetNotificationKey, object: nil, userInfo: nil)
}
```

Also, you need to make sure that you do all your UI work on the main queue, so in your `needMet` function, you should use [`dispatch_async`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/#//apple_ref/c/func/dispatch_async) to dispatch the work to the main queue:

```
func needMet() {
    startConnectionAt(url)

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
        tableView.reloadData()
        println("executed")
    }
}
```

***Note:** I'd recommend reading up on [Concurrency Programming](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ConcurrencyProgrammingGuide/Introduction/Introduction.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008091) to learn about `dispatch_async`, why you need use it, and some alternatives.*

You also seem to have defined `signupForNeed` inside `viewDidLoad`. That should really be a function in the class itself and not a nested function.

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much! (Just forgot my bracket in the example here on SO, my signupForNeed was outside of viewDidLoad). Thanks also for the link on Concurrency Programming. I've run into the dispatch main queue stuff before, but haven't really grasped it yet!